# How to set the logGroup programatically for CloudWatch using Nlog and MDLC

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, amazon-cloudwatch, nlog

I'm using AWS.Logger.NLog to send logs to CloudWatch.

What I'm trying to do is to assign the `logGroup` programatically, instead of putting it in the nlog.config. I tested other config parameters like the `region` and they work. I tested it putting the logGroup "hardcoded" in the nlog.config, like this:

```
<!-- This works -->
<target type="AWSTarget" name="aws" profile="hmrc" logGroup="TestGroup" region="${mdlc:region}">
```

But when I try with the `logGroup` I don't see the log messages in CW.

This is how my code looks:

```
// ...
var logContext = GetLogContext(context); // Get the logContext from the current Context
using (logger.BeginScope(logContext))
{
   MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Set("region", "eu-west-1"); // This works I see the logs in CW
   MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Set("loggroup", "TestGroup"); // This doesn't work, no logs
}
```

And the nlog.config:

```
<target type="AWSTarget" name="aws" profile="hmrc" logGroup="${mdlc:loggroup}" region="${mdlc:region}">
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Many of the [AWS properties](https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet/blob/f7e3e9be1a0c702401d8adde179cc8b5e2bb3164/src/NLog.AWS.Logger/AWSTarget.cs#L225) are only evaulated during target-initialization (static during application lifetime).

Comment: Ok, but makes no sense that the region (which should be more "static") can be changed dinamically and not the log group. It has to be a way.